# How to disambiguate when grabbing filename by the middle and there are several matches?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

In zsh with oh-my-zsh, I like how I can, within this directory for instance:

```
mydir/
  app.component.html
  app.component.ts
  app.module.ts
  app-routing.module.ts
```

type `./html<tab>` and have it automatically expanded as `./app.component.html`, even though the filename doesn't actually start with `html`, but it is a part that is characteristic.

Also, I can `./rout<tab>` to get `./app-routing.module.ts` with a middle clue.

If I use something ambiguous, like `./ts<tab>`, the experience is a bit weirder, since

- **1.** it first expands to the longest common part `./|.ts` (where `|` represents my cursor's position).
- **2.** on a second press to `<tab>` (why not the first?), I get a list of options displayed below:

```
$ ./|.ts
app.component.ts       app.module.ts
```

- **3.** on a third press to `<tab>` (why a third?), the first item of the list get selected.
- **4.** then, after one last `<tab>`, I finally get my expansion to `./app.module.ts`.

I understand that zsh needs more input since my initial clue was ambiguous, but I'm sure that 2 `<tabs>` would have been saved in the above process if the first `<tab>` directly resulted in **3.** instead of **1.** Is there anything I can configure about this?

Finally, if I use a non-terminal ambiguous clue, things start feeling clumsy. For instance `./mod<tab>` results in

- **1.** `./|d.module.ts` (not sure where this `d` comes from).
- **2.** a second `<tab>` just shifts the cursor to the end: `./d.module.ts|`.
- **+∞.** pressing `<tab>` does not change anything from this point on, or propose a list of options like it did before. So I end up scrolling back and fixing the filename myself.

I would have expected a list of options to be offered in only one `<tab>`, like in the previous case.

Is this expected behaviour?
Have I not understood quite well the way autocompletion is supposed to work?
Is this something I can configure, and how?

Comment: iago-lito: the Stack Exchange system has unfortunately run into some kind of bug (possibly https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345859/307535) regarding your question being closed as a duplicate of another one. For the time being, I'd like to reopen your question and ask if you could post a comment pointing to the Q/A that you think this is a duplicate of. Thank you!

Comment: @JeffSchaller Haha, I have been wondering whether it would cause a bug to self-close-as-duplicate, because it felt weird doing so X) Here is the post where I have finally found my answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12288/87656. Is it considered bad practise? Should I have closed instead?

Comment: Finding a duplicate and self-closing is perfectly fine! I assume we just encountered a software bug of some sort. I'll try closing it and see what happens.

Comment: Update: it seems the [glitch has been fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345859/307535)